# How to rename columns in a nested tibble based on the value of another column

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Sometimes I change column names of nested tibble depending on the value of another column.
I can do it preparing a function using in `map()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# sample data
d <- tibble(col1 = 1:8, col2 = 11:18, group = letters[rep(1:2, each = 4)]) %>%
  nest(-group)

f <- function(data, group) rename(data, !!paste0(group, "_col1") := col1)

# Run
desired_output <- d %>%
  mutate(data = map2(data, group, f))

names(desired_output$data[[1]])  # "a_col1" "col2"   # work
```

I want to do it by anonymous function, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to do like `mutate(map(rename(!!a := b)))` with anonymous function?
Thank you for any advice.

```
d %>%
  mutate(data2 = map2(data, group,
                      function(data, group) {
                        data %>%
                          rename(!!paste0(group, "_col1") := col1)
                      }))

# Error in paste0(group, "_col1") : object 'group' not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you exactly mean by anonymous function but here is a way to do this without having to assign the function `f` to a variable:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(data, group, ~rename_at(.x, 1, function(z) paste(.y, z, sep = "_"))))
```

Comment: Oh, your answer is JUST what I want. Thanks very much !!